# Using rules in postgresql to insert several rows

Tags: postgresql, postgis, rules

I need to insert several rows using a rule.

My problem is:
I draw a poligon and save on a table z0_poligono_corte, then I use a rule to get the intersection between the polygon in z0_poligono_corte and polygons in other table, but the result is not inserted in the table I created to save the results. Also there are no errors in the postgres log.

```
CREATE RULE cortar_anp AS ON INSERT TO z0_poligono_corte 
DO also insert into z0_a_n_p_13 (id_poligono, folio, obs, anp, geometria) select pol.id, pol.folio, pol.obs, capa.anp, ST_Multi(ST_Intersection(capa.geom, pol.geometria))
from a_n_p_13 capa, z0_poligono_corte pol
where pol.id=NEW.id
and capa.geom && pol.geometria
and ST_IsEmpty(ST_Intersection(capa.geom, pol.geometria)) != TRUE;
```

I don't know if my rule is correct. If I run the insert into sentence using for example pol.id=1 then the result saves correctly.
image

I have not 10 reputation to put the image :(

Here the image

Thanks.

Comment: Your current rule will attempt to insert records selected based on **all existing** records (**not** including the new record being inserted). Use `new` instead of `z0_poligono_corte pol` if you are only going to insert a record into `z0_a_n_p_13` corresponding to the record inserted to `z0_poligono_corte`.

Comment: like this: CREATE RULE cortar_anp AS ON INSERT TO z0_poligono_corte 
   DO also insert into z0_a_n_p_13 (id_poligono, folio, obs, anp, geometria) select new.id, new.folio, new.obs, capa.anp, ST_Multi(ST_Intersection(capa.geom, new.geometria))
from a_n_p_13 capa, NEW
where 
capa.geom && pol.geometria
and ST_IsEmpty(ST_Intersection(capa.geom, new.geometria)) != TRUE; but says that new relation don't exist. @ADTC

Comment: `capa.geom && pol.geometria AND ST_IsEmpty(ST_Intersection(capa.geom, pol.geometria)) != TRUE` is a really complicated way to ask if they intersect. It is greatly simplified as `ST_Intersects(capa.geom, pol.geometria)`.

Comment: Please look at [Postgres Docs about Rules](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/rules-update.html) to understand how to use `NEW` and `OLD` pseudorelations correctly, and what they are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how solved my problem with a trigger.
First i created a table

```
    CREATE TABLE public.z0_poligono_corte (   
id serial,   
nombre character varying(255),   
giro text,   
geometria geometry(MultiPolygon,32614),   
CONSTRAINT z0_poligono_corte_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) )
```

After that I created a trigger function that makes the slice

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.cortes_interseccion_amias()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    declare var_sql text;
    begin
        var_sql :=  'insert into z0_amias08 (id_poligono, nombre, giro, tipo, geometria) 
select pol.id, pol.nombre, pol.giro, capa.tipo, ST_Intersection(capa.geom, pol.geometria)
    from amias08 capa, z0_poligono_corte pol
    where pol.id=$1
    and capa.geom && pol.geometria
    and ST_IsEmpty(ST_Intersection(capa.geom, pol.geometria)) != TRUE';
        execute var_sql using NEW.id;
        return NEW;
    end;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
```

Then the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER interseccion_amias
  AFTER INSERT
  ON public.z0_poligono_corte
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.cortes_interseccion_amias();
```

So when I insert a polygon on that table, the trigger function will cut on the table with data, then insert on the new table